# Is it ok to write I go to USA for three days?

Tags: tense

I am wondering if it is grammatically right to say "I go to USA for three days or I went to USA for three days"
"go" or "went" is not a continuous word and should not be followed by a duration "for ".

Comment: "I went to the U.S.A. for three days" would ordinarily mean not that I spent three days going there but that I went to the U.S.A. and then stayed there for three days.

Comment: Are you back from your travels or is your travel still in the future? In any event it should be ***the*** USA.

Answer (score 2):

If your trip is in the future, you should say, "I am going to the U.S.A. for three days" or, "I am going to go to the U.S.A. for three days."

If your trip was in the past, you should say, "I went to the U.S.A. for three days."

Comment: but "go" is not a continuous word .How can it be followed by a duration of time  "for three days "?

Comment: Because the verb "to go" can be used as a continuous verb, meaning to move or travel. According to the O.E.D., "Go" is the most general verb of motion in English. You can speak of "going" on a walk, a voyage, a trip, or a journey for any length of time.

Answer (score 1):

The simple present tense is used to express habitual actions.  So you could say, for example, "I go to the US for three days every January."

The simple past tense is used to express a completed event.  So it is entirely normal to say "I went to the US for three days," provided you are no longer in the US.

Answer (score 1):

The word "go/went" has a range of meanings.  One of the meanings is "to visit for a purpose".  And in this sense the "for three days" is not the length of time travelling, but the length of the visit. "I went to the USA for three days" means the same as:

> I travelled to the USA and stayed for three days"

It is normal for common words like "go" to have a range of meanings, and they are always understood in context

Saying "I go to the USA for three days" is unusual.  There are some contexts in which it is possible ("I go to the USA for three days every summer") but normally you need some kind of future "tense" (I will go/I'm going/I plan to go etc)

If you are currently in the USA, you would just say "I'm staying in the USA for three days".